# Adding a value to a specific key in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am new to Python. I am learning dictionary . I want to insert a new value to an existing dictionary.
The existing dictionary is d={5:'acb',6:'bhg',7:'cssd'}.
I want to add a new value 'xsd' at key no 5, but i am not able to do so.
I have tried the below from my side. Please help.

```
d={5:'acb',6:'bhg',7:'cssd'}
d[5].append('xsd')
d
```

i want output as ;
d={5:['acb','xsd'],6:'bhg',7:'cssd'}

Comment: `d[5] = d[5] + 'xsd'`

Comment: i want them as separate elements as the following :
d={5:['acb','xsd'],6:'bhg',7:'cssd'}

Comment: if i m adding using + operator i m getting the following :
{5: 'acbxsd', 6: 'bhg', 7: 'cssd'}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
d = {5: 'acb', 6: 'bhg', 7: 'cssd'}
if type(d[5]) is list:
    d[5].append('xsd')
else:
    tmp = []
    tmp.append(d[5])
    tmp.append('xsd')
    d[5] = tmp
```

Comment: @ChayanMehrotra welcome. Please accept the answer if it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.pop`

```
>>> d[5] = [d.pop(5), 'xsd']
```

From Python `3.8` onwards, you can make it more flexible using `walrus operator`:

```
>>> d[5] = ( [*value, 'xsd'] 
             if isinstance((value := d.pop(5)), list) 
             else [value, 'xsd']
           )
```

Comment: If you could explain this ? pop() method removes the particular value from a key, after that how it is working ?

Comment: You `pop` the value of the key (eg. `'acb'`), and put it in a list with `xsd`, so `[d.pop(5), 'xsd']` is essentially `['acb', 'xsd']`, and you assign it back to `d[5]`

Comment: @ChayanMehrotra The pop() method removed the value `d[5]` from the dict, and returns the value (`'acb'` in the given case). Then the value `['acb', 'xsd']` is stored as `d[5]`